# Graph API error

Tags: php, api, graph

I'd like to include facebook login in my project using Graph Api v3.0.
That's the path of the interested files.

```
index.php
config.php
Facebook (folder)
   --> autoload.php
   --> Facebook.php
   --> other files..
```

That's the code inside config.php

```
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
$FB = new \Facebook\Facebook({          (Line 10)
     'app_id' => 'myappid',
     'app_secret' => 'myappsecret',
     'default_graph_version' => 'v3.0'
});
```

When I go to the url that execute config.php (index.php) it gives me that error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php on line 10
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You say the error is on line 10, but you've showed us only six lines. Which one is line 10? Can you show us *all* of the first 10 or so lines, please?

Answer (score -1):

```
#Did you try to remove this('()') on line 10 and line 14 ? As I remember JSON does not like brackets.
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
$FB = new \Facebook\Facebook{          /*(Line 10) or use '[' instead\*
     'app_id' => 'myappid',
     'app_secret' => 'myappsecret',
     'default_graph_version' => 'v3.0'
};
```